# paypal Some of your info isn't correct. Please try again

Tags: paypal

I am trying to login from my pappal sandbox account. I have made a subscription from my seller account and now I want to login into Paypal to buy the product with two different Paypal accounts.
I am getting this error continuously "Some of your info isn't correct. Please try again." I reset my password twice and I am stuck into this issue for hours. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't login at live checkout flow using sandbox account. Double check whether the checkout flow is sandbox (sandbox.paypal.com)  or live (paypal.com).

Comment: @PP_Punna The link is sandbox. Not sure why I have the same problem

Comment: Please create another sandbox account, try again this.

Comment: I am trying to do the same using java code, but received the same error.

Comment: I solved this issue myself. In my case, earlier the login page contained both username and password. Now it seems that the sandbox.paypal.com have modified it. Now the first page asks for email and 2nd asks for password. Once I modified the code accordingly, it worked. Important to note here, the second http.post request should contain both username and password, and not just the password alone (of course along with all other hidden attributes). Hope it might help someone.

Comment: I get the screen with both username and password inputs. I get the error this thread is dealing with. However I don't understand how to "modify the code accordingly".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about computer programming, and should be addressed to PayPal.

Answer (score 3):

You should create an account in PayPal sandbox
[here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#create-sandbox-accounts)

Once done, login your PayPal account and check your sandbox account here [here](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/)

Then you will see something like this, and these credentials is what you will be using to test the checkout page

[image: sample credentials]